# Why doesnt it replace the char?

Tags: java, string, input, replace, chars

The string "displayed" are filled with * and its just as long as the string "secret".
and secret is a word from an array.

```
public void replace(String input)
    {

        for (int j = 0; j < displayed.length(); j++)
        {
           if (input.charAt(0) == secret.charAt(j))  
           {
             displayed1 = displayed.replace(secret.charAt(j), input.charAt(0));

            //System.out.print(input.charAt(0) == secret.charAt(j) ? input.charAt(0) : "*");
           }
        }

        System.out.println(displayed1);
```

when i run this its gives me only *, it doesnt replace the * with the input.
but if let print it, it replaces it..

im fairly new at programming, so it might be a stupid little thing as allways, but i cant find it :(

Comment: I think you misunderstand the `String.replace` method. Given 2 parameters, it finds all the occurrences of the first character in the string, and replaces them with the second character. But this string only has "*" inside it. It doesn't have any character from `secret`. So it doesn't replace anything. It only replaces a character if it exists inside of it.

Comment: Ofcourse..stupid me :(
it cant be done like this, i need to rethink :)

Comment: Replacing whole text with * if u dont want to reveal the value,  Use no of * to represent the string e.g. User will be **** and show if thr string if user clicks button or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `secret.charAt(j)` is equal to `input.charAt(0)`, the call of `displayed.replace` cannot possibly have any effect, because you are replacing a character with the same character. Say, `secret.charAt(j)` is `'x'`; then your call is equivalent to

```
displayed1 = displayed.replace('x', 'x');
```

which is equivalent to `displayed1 = displayed`, and is definitely not what you want to do.

Moreover, `displayed` consists of asterisks, so the letter from `secret.charAt(j)` cannot even be there. What you probably want is to compose your string character by character, rather than using a sequence of repeated replacements:

```
char[] chars = displayed;
for (int j = 0; j < displayed.length(); j++) {
    if (input.charAt(0) == secret.charAt(j)) {
        chars[j] = secret.charAt(j);
    }
}
displayed = new String(chars);
System.out.println(displayed);
```

The code above uses a character array to change the string. You could also use [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html), a mutable string object, to achieve the same effect.